# How to get a UIView to "Wrap Content" in iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiview, constraints

Firstly, it's worth noting I am using Xamarin. I'm familiar with Swift so i'm happy for any answers to be given using swift code. More importantly, all my views are built programmatically using constrains, without storyboard or Xib, since I find them a bit of a pain to work with in Xamarin.

I'm looking for something that works very similar to "wrap_content" in android. Basically, I have a View with 2 subviews within it. These views are side by side and together take up the full width of the screen. The first view is a fixed height, the second has a variable height that can increase of decrease to be both greater than and less than the fixed height of the first view.

Ultimately, I want whichever is the smallest view to be centred vertically within the parent view.

In android this is very easy, I just wrap content, set the gravity to centre and programmatically adjust the size of the subviews accordingly. Android then resizes the parent view accordingly. However, in iOS I find this to be a real challenge.

Equally, if there are any materials out there which help with how to implement wrapping content in iOS that would be equally beneficial as I seem to run into a similar issue to this every other day.

Comment: Isn't a `UIStackView` what you want? (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview - the first example displays your intended behavior, as far as I understand it). I'm not sure if it is available in Xamarin though.

Comment: It seems it is : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uistackview?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

Comment: @Losiowaty This is exactly what I needed. I wish I new about this view a month ago, would have saved me so much work. Feel free to answer and take the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments - a `UIStackView` can be used to achieve this.
It needs to be configured with `axis = .horizontal` and `alignment = .center` to achieve the configuration described in the question.

Documentation :
Apple : [UIStackView](http://healthCheckerEnabled:%20healthCheckerEnabled,) (the first image actually shows layout as described in the question, just with more than 2 subviews).
Xamarin : [Xamarin UIStackView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uistackview?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

Comment: The link doesn't work for UIStackView, is it possible to relink it?